# Laravel entrust return user with roles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Am using Zizaco entrust package and trying to get all users together with their roles

User model i have

```
 use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
   use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

  class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
  {
    use Authenticatable,HasApiTokens, EntrustUserTrait;

       protected $fillable = [
         'name', 'email', 'password','status'
       ];


       protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
      ];


     public function role()
     {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'id');
     }

}
```

Now the App\Role

```
use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

 class Role extends EntrustRole
  {

 }
```

Whenver i fetch my users with

```
     $sortval = explode("|",$request->sort);
    return \App\User::orderBy( $sortval[0],  $sortval[1])
                ->with("role") //added the relationship
                ->paginate($request->per_page);
```

The above role always returns null even when there are assigned roles to users.

Comment: have you tried moving the "with" to the front, then orderBY

Comment: still fails to work

Comment: what does this return 

"return \App\User::with("role");"

Comment: returns user data but with an empty role.

Comment: @ATechGuy by not setting the role relationship in the user model now it has started working. Its bizzare though

Comment: You were over-riding `role` relation declared already in `EntrustUserTrait`. Even so Role and User share a many-to-many relation and you should be using `belongsToMany` anyway.